# How to document a mixed typed array structures in requests/responses with Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

Given the following exemplary JSON document, which is a list of polymorphic objects of type A and B:

```
[ {
  "a" : 1,
  "type" : "A"
}, {
  "b" : true,
  "type" : "B"
}, {
  "b" : false,
  "type" : "B"
}, {
  "a" : 2,
  "type" : "A"
} ]
```

How would I be able to select the As and the Bs to be able to document them differently.

I put an example project on github: `https://github.com/dibog/spring-restdocs-polymorphic-list-demo`

Here is an excerpt of me trying to document the fetch method:

```
.andDo(document("fetch-tree",
                responseFields(
                    beneathPath("[0]").withSubsectionId("typeA"),
                    fieldWithPath("type")
                        .type(JsonFieldType.STRING)
                        .description("only node types 'A' and 'B' are supported"),
                    fieldWithPath("a")
                        .type(JsonFieldType.NUMBER)
                        .description("specific field for node type A")
                ),
                responseFields(
                    beneathPath("[1]").withSubsectionId("typeB"),
                    fieldWithPath("type")
                        .type(JsonFieldType.STRING)
                        .description("only node types 'A' and 'B' are supported"),
                    fieldWithPath("b")
                        .type(JsonFieldType.BOOLEAN)
                        .description("specific field for node type A")
                )))
```

But I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadHandlingException: [0] identifies multiple sections of the payload and they do not have a common structure. The following non-optional uncommon paths were found: [[0].a, [0].b]
```

It looks like that [0] or [1] does not work and is interpreted as []. 
What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks,
Dieter

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like that [0] or [1] does not work and is interpreted as [].

That's correct. Adding support for indices is being tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/468).

> What would be the best way to handle this situation?

The `beneathPath` method that you've tried to use above returns an implementation of a strategy interface, `PayloadSubsectionExtractor`. You could provide your own implementation of this interface and, in the `extractSubsection(byte[], MediaType)` method, extract the JSON for a particular element in the array and return it as a `byte[]`.

Comment: I have created a quick solution which works for lists. Maybe you can have a look at it?